SCSI/IDE/SATA cards for booting from ODD with widest coverage of x86* mainboards/BIOSes
Summarize the problem
I am searching for a small set of PCI/PCIe disk controllers which would allow booting from Optical disk drive (ODD) on as many x86* machines as possible.
My aim is to have a list of specific cards that would work on worldwide scope (including both old and new machines).
Provide details and any research
A card needs to:

implement SCSI, IDE, or SATA interface;
have the Optional ROM;
be compatible with x86 CPUs (starting from Intel Pentium);
be supported by BIOS (legacy) machines  
that can boot from SCSI/PCI add-in cards;
be supported by UEFI machines;
support booting from ODD (CD or DVD drive),  
not only from a hard disk (which is the usual scenario);

When appropriate, describe what you’ve tried
I tried googling for possible card models, but I see a lot of matches where such cards fail to boot from connected ODDs. Eg:

Adding a PCI SATA controller and booting from it?
BOOT from add-on PCI card - HOWTO?
Boot from cd with ide controller
Boot from cd using pci ide card
Boot from IDE CD-ROM...
Booting from PCI IDE
Can't boot with DVD drive on IDE controller card
How to boot from a cdrom drive connected to a pci sata card?
PCI IDE to CDROM not working
PCI IDE Controller
PCI SATA controllers questions

I also found some statements about working setups:

Is it possible to boot to DOS using a PCI to IDE card? 
(Promise Ultra100, Promise S150 SATA, Adaptec AHA-2940 series cards)
Booting from PCI IDE 
(Promise Ultra66, some PCI adapter card with VIA chipset and IDE interface)

But the success stories are very rare and pretty vague.

So I would be grateful for any specific models known to work this way (and other tips) from your practical experience (as opposed to theoretical experience).
